# How to make own language file in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to make my own language file for my installer. I want to make my installer which will support two languages "English" and "Hindi". But there is no language file for hindi. So I want to make my own language file for hindi. Can anyone tell me how to make it and how to link it with NSIS? And what is ".nlf" files e.g "English.nlf" present in the NSIS Contrib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nlf` files inside `Contrib\Language files` are storing all default dialogs used by NSIS. The `.nsh` files in the same folder are used by installers with Modern UI. I'd clone the files for English translation (or any other language you prefer as starting point) and change all the strings inside.

For your convenience, there are packages available for [Sublime Text](https://github.com/idleberg/NSIS-Language-File-Sublime-Text) and [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/language-nlf), that let you jump between each translation field.

Comment: Thanks it' working but the font appearing on the installer pages is looking very small as compared to english language. How can I increase the font size so that it will look nice?

Comment: Yes, replace the - below `# Font and size - dash (-) means default` with a font size (I think it's without unit)

Comment: Yes and it also increases the size of window. I have written new language file for HINDI that was not previously available by nsis. How can I contribute my work for NSIS. I want to give my language files to NSIS for future work. What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by idleberg, you just copy one of the .nlf and .nsh files and translate the strings but you are in luck, the NSIS fork already has a [almost complete translation](https://github.com/jimpark/unsis/tree/master/unicode-src/Contrib/Language%20files/Unicode).

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks  friend